# Elastic Search - Xpack security password change

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I had generated passwords for elastic search using below command and I forgot to copy and backup passwords shown at console output

```
sudo -E ./elasticsearch-setup-passwords auto
```

When I tried executing it again , I am not able to regenerate passwords again, please help me in taking those passwords or guide me how to change password for user **elastic**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/configuring-security.html):

> The elasticsearch-setup-passwords command uses a transient bootstrap password that is no longer valid after the command runs successfully. You cannot run the elasticsearch-setup-passwords command a second time. **Instead, you can update passwords from the Management > Users UI in Kibana or use the security user API.**

As stated in the part in bold, you can simply update the passwords from the Kibana UI.

Answer (score 4):

If you are not able to login kibana due to password not working and authentication error please use below process

1. Stop elasticsearch
2. Go to directory elasticsearch/bin
3. Create new super user via below

> ./elasticsearch-users useradd elasticadmin -p elasticadmin -r
> superuser

4. Start elasticsearch process
5. Try running below command with new user you should get user list:

> curl -u elasticadmin -XGET
> 'http://localhost:9200/_xpack/security/user?pretty'
>
> ```
> Enter host password for user 'newadmin':
> ```
>
> {   "elastic" : {
> "username" : "elastic",
> "roles" : [
> "superuser"
> ],
> "full_name" : null,
> "email" : null,
> "metadata" : {
> "_reserved" : true
> },
> "enabled" : true   },   "kibana" : {
> "username" : "kibana",
> "roles" : [
> "kibana_system"
> ],
> "full_name" : null,

6. Run below curl command to change password of elastic user.

> curl --user elasticadmin:#l@$t!c@dm!n -XPUT
> "http://localhost:9200/_xpack/security/user/elastic/_password?pretty"
> -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{ "password" :  "typeyourpasswordhere"}'

7. Try login elasticsearch with new password of elastic user

> curl -u elastic -XGET "http://localhost:9200/"

8. In the similar way you can change password of kibana or other users as well